# remote connection from WP8 to ubuntu 12.04

Tags: connection, remote, windows-phone

Is it possible to establish something like a remote desktop connection from a Windows Phone 8 based phone to Ubuntu? I just migrated my desktop from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 12.04. So I'm pretty much an Ubuntu newby. Basically, I would like to kick off some scripts for calculating stuff (physics) and check on the results remotely.

Comment: Not to dissuade you, but why not use wolfram alpha from your phone?

Comment: because it won't let me run those Quantum Monte Carlo simulations 

Comment: (you assume i know what you're talking about)

Comment: I basically want to have the computing power of my desktop available even when I'm not at home. It's no problem to do this from a laptop, so doing it over the phone would just be a nice to have

Comment: ok, so a referral to wolframalpha, that's all? isn't this a totally valid question?

Comment: You need patience.  :P  Don't expect instant responses.  This is a valid question, but you need patience until someone comes along who can know the answer.